# DlibDotNet cannot detect faces in bitmap stream from webcam

Tags: c#, winforms, dlib

i have a method to get the video from the webcam as a bitmap stream, and i have a method to detect faces from a picture and draw a rectangle around them

```
public void start_cam_stream()
        {
            string[] devices = UsbCamera.FindDevices();
            if (devices.Length == 0) MessageBox.Show("no camera");

            int cameraIndex = 0;
            UsbCamera.VideoFormat[] formats = UsbCamera.GetVideoFormat(cameraIndex);

            var camera = new UsbCamera(cameraIndex, formats[0]);
            camera.Start();

            var bmp = camera.GetBitmap();
            

            var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(100) { SynchronizingObject = this };
            //timer.Elapsed += (s, ev) => pictureBox1.Image = camera.GetBitmap();
            timer.Elapsed += (s, ev) => detectfaces(camera.GetBitmap()); 

            timer.Start();

            


            // release resource when close.
            this.FormClosing += (s, ev) => timer.Stop();
            this.FormClosing += (s, ev) => camera.Stop();

        }

        public void detectfaces(Bitmap original_bmp)
        {
            Bitmap imgbmp;
            var img = DlibDotNet.Extensions.BitmapExtensions.ToArray2D<RgbPixel>(original_bmp);

            using (var fd = Dlib.GetFrontalFaceDetector())
            {



                // find all faces in the image
                var faces = fd.Operator(img);
                foreach (var face in faces)
                {
                    // draw a rectangle for each face
                    Dlib.DrawRectangle(img, face, color: new RgbPixel(0, 255, 255), thickness: 4);
                }
                detectedbmp = BitmapExtensions.ToBitmap<RgbPixel>(img);

            }
            pictureBox1.Image = original_bmp;
            pictureBox2.Image = detectedbmp;
        }
```

what i am trying to do is to take each bitmap from camera.GetBitmap() and apply the method "detectfaces()" to it and put the "modified bitmaps" in the second picture box.

the detectfaces method works properly when working with a single image, plus i convert the bitmap to a 2Darray so the Dlib can work with it and convert it back to bmp so it can be displayed in the picturebox.

However when i execute both pictureboxes stay blank as if i didn't apply anything to their "Image" property

this is my first time working with facial recognition libaries and stuff like this so i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong and google isn't that helpful in this case.

if anyone has a totally different solution that works properly (using other libraries than dlib) i'm ready to try it.

(ps: the camera work is done by this guy https://github.com/secile/UsbCamera)

Comment: You aren't disposing of GDI objects (like `Bitmap`) correctly. You're going to hit your User32 resource limits quickly.

Comment: i managed to **partially** solve this problem, even though there are some resources that still make the memory consumption ascend (but not rapidly like before)